# CSV how to add and subtract totals of a column to get a final balance

Tags: python, csv

I have a bank statement with a column of debit amounts and a column of credit amounts. I want to be able to add up all of the credit and all of the debit, and given with the input of an initial balance be able to predict the end balance. Then, I would like to cross check that value calculated with one given through an input. If the values are not the same, I would like the entire program to give an error message and not work to avoid mistakes. Some of the cells in these columns are blank too. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
cv = csv.reader(open(bank_statement, 'r'))

# here I am trying to fill all empty cells with 0s because empty cells were causing another error message

def recode_empty_cells(dataframe, list_of_columns):
    for column in list_of_columns:
        dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].replace(r'\s+', 0, regex=True)
        dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].fillna(0)
    return dataframe


def change_string_to_int(dataframe, list_of_columns):
    dataframe = recode_empty_cells(dataframe, list_of_columns)
    for column in list_of_columns:
        try:
            dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].astype(int)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return dataframe

credit_total = sum(int(float(row[5])) for row in bank_statement)
    debit_total = sum(int(float(row[4])) for row in bank_statement)
    end_bal_added_1 = str(int(float(initial_bal)) + int(float(credit_total)))
    end_bal_added_2 = int(end_bal_added_1) - int(float(debit_total))

   if int(end_bal_added_2) != int(float(end_bal)):
      print("End Balance is not the sum of all debit and credit")
print(str(int(credit_total)))
```

The error message that I get is this even though the CSV file that I have attached has 8 columns:

```
credit_total = sum(int(float(row[5])) for row in bank_statement)
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Here is a sample of the csv that I am using:

```
Account Number,Post Date,Check,Description,Debit,Credit,Status,Balance
xxxxxx5287,4/20/20,,Super Interesting Description 1,19642.42,,Pending,
xxxxxx5287,4/17/20,,Super Interesting Description 2,,174819.23,Posted,185623.13
xxxxxx5287,4/16/20,,Super Interesting Description 3,1240.51,,Posted,10803.9
xxxxxx5287,4/15/20,,Super Interesting Description 4,546.83,,Posted,12044.41
xxxxxx5287,4/14/20,,Super Interesting Description 1,22227,,Posted,12591.24
xxxxxx5287,4/14/20,,Super Interesting Description 2,323757.63,,Posted,34818.24
xxxxxx5287,4/14/20,,Super Interesting Description 3,,323757.63,Posted,358575.87
xxxxxx5287,4/10/20,,Super Interesting Description 4,9960.75,,Posted,34818.24
xxxxxx5287,4/10/20,,Super Interesting Description 1,9531,,Posted,44778.99
xxxxxx5287,4/9/20,,Super Interesting Description 2,202.5,,Posted,54309.99
xxxxxx5287,4/9/20,,Super Interesting Description 3,126500,,Posted,54512.49
xxxxxx5287,4/9/20,,Super Interesting Description 4,32257.25,,Posted,181012.49
xxxxxx5287,4/9/20,,Super Interesting Description 1,5,,Posted,213269.74
xxxxxx5287,4/9/20,,Super Interesting Description 2,,208593.19,Posted,213274.74
xxxxxx5287,4/3/20,,Super Interesting Description 3,15909.2,,Posted,4681.55
xxxxxx5287,4/2/20,,Super Interesting Description 4,3722.5,,Posted,20590.75
xxxxxx5287,4/2/20,,Super Interesting Description 1,2380,,Posted,24313.25
xxxxxx5287,4/1/20,,Super Interesting Description 2,1068.98,,Posted,26693.25
xxxxxx5287,4/1/20,,Super Interesting Description 3,436.08,,Posted,27762.23
xxxxxx5287,4/1/20,,Super Interesting Description 4,413.02,,Posted,28198.31
xxxxxx5287,4/1/20,,Super Interesting Description 1,88.7,,Posted,28611.33
xxxxxx5287,4/1/20,,Super Interesting Description 2,72.78,,Posted,28700.03
```

Comment: Are you sure every single row has the 8 cells?  You can use a `try` statement to catch the error. When it catches have the `except` block print the entire row and you will see where it is choking

Comment: ``print(bank_statement)``, it might not be list instead a string.

Comment: Could you show me what you mean by the try statement? I am really new to this so I am not completely clear on how to do this.

Comment: I have a total of 8 columns, and each column has 462 rows. Some cells are blank though.

Comment: @AnnaMobley  Looks like you figured out the `try` statement mostly. Make sure the section that is breaking is in the `try` block. And for TESTING do not use `ValueError` just do this -- `except: print(current_row)`  -- Obviously replace 'current_row' with what you are using

Comment: @AnnaMobley Could you print out the rows and edit in a couple lines of the printed rows. I think Sushanth may be correct and you may not be working with the lists the way you think you are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure where you are hitting a snag, but I think you are over thinking this a little bit. If you are just trying to sum a couple rows try this block. This isn't everything you need but it should be enough to get you started

```
with open(bank_statement, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')
    data = data[1:] # Removes Headers
    data = [x.split(',') for x in data] # Break each row into its own list

    debit_total = 0
    credit_total = 0
    for row in data:
        try:
            debit_total += float(row[4])
        except ValueError:
            pass

        try:
            credit_total += float(row[5])
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

If that accomplishes what you need you should be able to expand it to get the rest of the data. If you have any questions just comment and I'll see if I can help.

**EDIT**
Sorry, forgot you had null values. I updated to handle null fields

Comment: I have now copied a sample of my csv edited into my original question I am not sure if this is helpful for you to help me figure out what is going wrong, but it is worth a shot. I am still getting the error 'debit_total += float(row[4])'  'IndexError: list index out of range'. But as you can see, I have over 6 columns. Could you give me an example of the code that I would write to see if what you and @Sushanth would help me?

Comment: @AnnaMobley I fixed the issue that was causing your error. Try this one now. You may have to change the index. I was getting nothing for credit total, I'm guessing bc of that.

Comment: @AnnaMobley nevermind, I realized what I did wrong. Should work better now.

Comment: @AnnaMobley glad I could help